# How to remove stars and other objects from a galaxy FITS image using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fits

I have the following image in fits format. I want to remove all the stars and other smaller dots from that image using matlab.[image]

I performed the following matlab operations to remove stars in it.

```
I = imread('NGC_0253.jpg');
if size(I,3)==3
   I=rgb2gray(I);
end
K = imcomplement(I);
L = I-K;
M = medfilt2(L);
imshow(M)
```

I am getting image like this:[image]

I also try the following:

```
I = imread('NGC_0253.jpg');
if size(I,3)==3
   I=rgb2gray(I);
end
K = imcomplement(I);
L = I-K;
M = bwareaopen(L,1000);
N = medfilt2(M);
imshow(N)
```

but it also does not satisfy me:[image]

Which is not my objective. My objective is to remove all the stars from the image.

So, What should I do to remove all the stars leaving the galaxy intact from the image?

Comment: Just letting you know: this is a very good question in SO, thanks for making the effort of posing the question properly and showing what you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `bwareaopen` I get a good result. (I use your second image as input, so you can keep the first part of your code)

```
I = imread('NGC_0253.jpg');
I = im2bw(I,0.5); %the second parameter correspond to the threshold ∈ [0-1]
I = ~bwareaopen(~I,400); %where 400 = the minimal number of connected pixel needed to not be removed.

imshow(I)
```

**INPUT:**

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**Improvement:**

To be more precise it can be useful to compute the parameters of the ellipse.

[image]

To do that you can use the function `fit_ellipse` available on fileexchange.

```
Iedge = edge(mat2gray(I),'Canny');
[x,y] = find(Iedge');
hold on
A = fit_ellipse(x,y,h);
```

Comment: fast and effective, I like it!

Comment: This also removed the shadow of the galaxy, which does not need to be removed.

Comment: @AnStudent then you should modify the `level`. See the documentation on [`im2bw`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html).